# Unable to show image properly using Vanillabox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use Vanillabox, which I just downloaded from http://cocopon.me/app/vanillabox/index.html.

I have implemented it to show an image on my application:

```
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Guarantee</title>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="vanillabox/theme/bitter/vanillabox.css">
     <script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="vanillabox/jquery.vanillabox.js"></script>
</head>
```

...............

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: left">
        <a id="singleimage" href="images/testimonies/Rolls Royce Testimony 
        Highlighted.JPG" style="color: black; font-weight: bold;">Rolls Royce 
        Testimony Highlighted</a>
</div>
```

...............

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#singleimage").vanillabox({
               closeButton: true
           });
       });
   </script>    
</body>
```

However, instead of an image modal type showing on my test webpage, clicking the link shows up as another page on the browser - where I have to click on "back" to return to my web application.

What am I missing to make the image click work correctly?

I have verified the paths of the js and css files:

[image]

Comment: try including jquery migrate as well... I had the same error as you with vanillabox, and my error was resolved by updating an old version of jquery, so maybe migrate will fix it for you

Comment: You are right Veksen. I solved it later that day by updating to the latest jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the problem right away, but you can check your browser's javascript console for more details. Seems like the vanillabox is not activated for some reason.

EDIT: this should have gone in the comments of the OP, but for some reason I didn't saw "add comment" ???

Comment: Hi. I am testing using IE, Chrome and Mozilla. Not showing on any. How do I check the javascript console in Chrome?

Comment: F12 or ctrl-shift-j should open the js console. It's very helpful tool for web development.

Comment: Ahh. the line  $("#singleimage").vanillabox({ is showing an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in Chrome.

Comment: It seems you haven't included vanillabox correctly in the header.
Check out your path "vanillabox/jquery.vanillabox.js". Keep in mind it's a relative path, not absolute.

Comment: Check the permissions on vanillabox folder and all files and subfolders inside. Perhaps the web server cannot access them. You can verify it with the browser http://yourserver.tld/vanillabox/jquery.vanillabox.js . It should open the JS or give error if there is problem with the permissions.

Comment: I have checked the permissions. They are Ok.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51705/discussion-between-0xaf-and-kinyanjui-kamau)